# Statistical comparison of the lengths of the shortest and simplest paths

Tags: graphs-and-networks

pn= [image];

1) What built-in functions can we use to get statistics similar to those in this publication http://www.nature.com/articles/srep03495.

2) What built-in function  give a graph distribution ? could not find something like "GraphDistribution" for example in the documentation center.

Comment: You may want to explain what your are looking for in terms of graph "complexity" . Maybe maximum node degree would be relevant, as it seems to be quite low. Also, what is WL?

Comment: Please have a look [over here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see and learn how to formulate a well received question here on **Mathematica.SE**. Usually people around here are really into graph-related questions so with some effort on your part this might be a interesting question attracting lots of answers.

Comment: @A.G. Thank you for your consideration. That's figure out  precisely what I am trying to figure out . I  found  kind of the same question here : http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/587818 WL stands for Wolfram Language.

Comment: @Sacha. I am aware of these rules and I will  go over them and master them as soon as  I defend my doctoral thesis in a couple of  weeks.  Right now ,my priority  to  get help to analyze my data. So please be patient and bear with me for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph is planar (as far as I can see) and is not connected (there is a lonely edge and a number of small connected components). That explains the output of `EdgeConnectivity` and `VertexConnectivity`.

Comment: @A.G.Thank you again. Please check out this. http://www.nature.com/articles/srep03495